# rails condition query for search form

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How to do search query in rails. My `params` is

```
"search"=>{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"selva", "item_id"=>""}
```

and what I have tried

```
User.where("id = ? AND name = ? AND item_id = ?", params["search"]["id"],params["search"]["name"],params["search"]["item_id"])
```

Here problem is when `params` comes empty, then it trough error. So can you suggest me what is best way to search and how people are searching form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something Like that

```
users = User

if params['search']
  search_data = params['search']
  users = users.where(:id => search_data['id']) if search_data['id']
  users = users.where(:name => search_data['name']) if search_data['name']
  users = users.where(:item_id => search_data['item_id']) if search_data['item_id']
end

users = users.all
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `users = User.all`?  Then you could eliminate the last line.

Comment: User.all will run a query. Keeping it for last makes sure we only talk to the db once.